# logoff a user from all pages if logged of on one page mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to log off a user from all windows open in a browser like gmail in mvc. I am currently using a Ajax response with javascript to invoke a reload in page every 15 seconds but just curious to know if there is some built in function in mvc that can do this. My code is as follows also if this is the only method i.e **some timed response** what is the optimal timer intervals from your experience?

In my shared layout window

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
            setInterval(function () { loadchkDoc() }, 15000);
        }
        function loadchkDoc(){
            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "/Home/chkDoc", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    var k = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    if (k == "gotologin") {
                        location.reload();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
   }
```

In my Home controller

```
public string chkDoc()
        {
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return "authorized";
            }
            else
            {
                return "gotologin";
            }
        }
```

Comment: There is no built-in function to do this. You could take a look at SignalR as an alternative to using interval timers.

Comment: Thanks Robs i will have a look at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of invoke ajax request you can try check if you have authentication cookie. That need to set cookie `HttpOnly` to false.

```
function checkSession() {
    if (!$.cookie('.ASPXAUTH')) {
        logout();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(checkSession, 15);
    }
}
```

Of course that solution resolve only case when user click log off. Additionally you can create another cookie that persist session timeout and check if that timeout doesn't  expired.

Comment: Although it works but I get the Jquery errors when using this. `Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
  // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
  return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
 } has no method 'cookie'`

Comment: Yes, because you must download jquery.cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie